# Needs to return only the matched nested objects with full parent body using hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to do exactly same things as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759718/needs-to-return-only-the-matched-nested-objects-with-full-parent-body-in-elastic) using the hibernate criteria. please let me know if it is possible and how?

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share an example of what you have tried so we can help troubleshoot?  [This guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help get you started.

Comment: I have mentioned the similar example link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759718/needs-to-return-only-the-matched-nested-objects-with-full-parent-body-in-elastic